# "Variable must be initialized" for companion object with initializer

Tags: kotlin, enums, initialization

I don't understand what is wrong with this code:

```
enum class Example(val property: Int) {
    ONE(333),
    TWO(444),
    THREE(555);
    init {
        propertyToEnum[property] = this
    }
    companion object {
        private val propertyToEnum = mutableMapOf<Int,Example>()
        fun reverseLookup(property: Int): Example? {
            return propertyToEnum[property]
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler is flagging an error "Variable 'propertyToEnum' must be initialized" inside the `init` block, but that variable has an initializer inside the `companion` object. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the companion object is not initialized until after the enum values, you could change it like this to fill your map only when the companion object is being initialized.

```
enum class Example(val property: Int) {
    ONE(333),
    TWO(444),
    THREE(555);
    
    companion object {
        private val propertyToEnum = values().associateBy { it.property }
        fun reverseLookup(property: Int): Example? {
            return propertyToEnum[property]
        }
    }
}
```